# gdb do not echo my input until I press Enter

Tags: linux, shell, gdb

We have an embedded device running linux. What I type in can be echoed instantly in shell, but when I start gdb , I can not see any user input until I press the Enter key.Here is an example:

```
sh-4.3# ls  
/tmp  
sh-4.3# gdb  
GNU gdb (Debian 7.7.1+dfsg-5) 7.7.1  
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc  
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.  
 <------(I already type "shell ls", but nothing echoed in the screen)  
(gdb)shell ls      <------(then I press Enter key, and things come out)  
/tmp
```

What is the difference in these two situations?